# Entropy of the product of two random variables

Tags: probability, inequality, entropy

Consider a random matrix $X$ and a random vector $Y$. Let the Shannon entropies $H(X) = H(Y) = n$.  Is there a simple upper bound for entropy $H(XY)$?  I believe $H(XY) \leq 2n$ as that is a simple upper bound for the joint entropy of $(X,Y)$, but is it also the case that $H(XY) \leq n$?

---

The entries of $X$ need not be independent. $X$ is $m$ by $n$ for some $m \leq n$ and $Y$ has $n$ entries.

Comment: Why do you think that H(XY) would be at most n?

Comment: @Did I just couldn't think of an example where the entropy is higher.  Is there in fact a simple example?

Comment: what are the dimensions of our matrix $X$?  Are all the entries independent?  What is the size of your vector $Y$? @Lembik

Comment: @johnmangual The entries of $X$ need not be independent. $X$ is $m$ by $n$ for some $m \leq n$ and $Y$ has $n$ entries.

Comment: I think your argument is that $H(XY)\le H(X) + H(Y)$, and I think that is pretty obviously correct. If the mapping $(X,Y)\mapsto XY$ is invertible, then clearly equality holds,  i.e., $H(XY) = H(X) + H(Y)$. It's easy to construct examples where this is the case. For example, let $X=\text{diag}(\pm 1,1)$ with equal probability and let $Y=[1\ \  \pm1]^T$ with equal probability. It's then easy to see that one can "reconstruct" $X$ and $Y$ from knowledge of $XY$, and so $H(XY) = H(X)+H(Y)$.

Comment: @WillNelson I am even more confused now :) Is your comment compatible with fabee 's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Differential entropy**

I don't think that you can derive an upper bound for the following reason.

Let's assume $Y \sim \mathcal N(0,\eta I)$ is Gaussian distributed (with $\eta$ chosen such that $H[Y]=n$) and $X \sim \mathcal N(\lambda O, \kappa I)$, where $\kappa$ is chosen such that $H[X]=n$, $O$ a matrix consisting of ones, and $\lambda$ a free parameter which we are going to play around with.

For $\lambda=1$ the entropy of will have some value $H[XY]=c$ . However, since the differential entropy depends on scale, increasing $\lambda$ will also increase $H[XY]$. More specifically, for arbitrary $\lambda$
$$H[XY]=H\left[\frac{1}{\lambda} XY\right]+n\log \lambda=c + n\log \lambda.$$

Since $\lambda$ only changes the mean of $X$, is does not affect its marginal entropy $H[X]$. However, as you can see, the entropy $H[XY]$ can be made arbitrarily large by increasing $\lambda$. Therefore, there is no upper bound in terms of the single marginal entropies.

It might help to know the transformation formula for discrete entropies. Maybe this can make it clearer that the differential entropy changes under a deterministic function $f$.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and that we want to know $H\left[Y\right]$ in terms of $H\left[X\right]$ where $Y=f(X)$:

\begin{align}H\left[Y\right]  &=  \left\langle -\log p_{Y}(Y)\right\rangle _{Y}\\
  &=  \left\langle -\log p_{Y}(f(X))\right\rangle _{X}\\
  &=  \left\langle -\log\left(\underbrace{p_{Y}(f(X))\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|}_{p_{X}(X)}\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|^{-1}\right)\right\rangle _{X}\\
  &=  H\left[X\right]+\left\langle \log\left(\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|\right)\right\rangle _{X}.
\end{align}

**Discrete entropy (after discussion with Will Nelson in the comments)**
Will was right that for discrete entropy and a deterministic function, one can show that $$H[XY]=H[f(X,Y)]\le H[X] + H[Y].$$
The reason (which can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Further_properties)) is that 
$$0 \le H[Z,f(Z)]=H[Z] + H[f(Z)|Z] = H[Z|f(Z)] + H[f(Z)]$$
and the fact that $H[f(Z)|Z]=0$ for deterministic $f$.

How can we apply this to the case above? First of all, we know that 
$$2n \ge H[X,Y] \ge n.$$
This follows from $H[X,Y] = H[X] + H[Y|X]$, $H[Y|X]\ge 0$ and the fact that conditioning reduces entropy.

So if $X$ and $Y$ are completely dependent, then $H[X,Y] = n \ge H[XY]$. Whether $H[XY]=H[X,Y]=n$ depends on $H[X,Y|XY]=0$ which is the case if the nullspace of $XY$ is zero for all $X$.

So we know now that $H[XY]\le H[X,Y]$ and under which conditions this would be equal to $n$. Of course one could still have $H[X,Y]>n$ and $H[XY]\le n$, but without any further knowledge of the distribution $p(X,Y)$ I have no idea how to show anything better.

Comment: I am a little confused. I had assumed that the joint entropy $H(X,Y) = 2n$ and that therefore $H(f(X,Y)) \leq 2n$.  Is that not even right?

Comment: The joint entropy of $X$ and $Y$ is only $2n$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Why would you expect $H[f(X,Y)]\le 2n$? For example, if $f:\mathbb R^{2n+m}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{2n+m}$, then $H\left[f(X,Y)\right] = H\left[X,Y\right]+\left\langle \log\left(\left|\frac{df}{d(x,y)}\right|\right)\right\rangle _{X,Y}$. Depending on $f$ this can de- or increase the entropy. E.g. if $f$ just multiplies with a constant greater than one, you will always increase the differential entropy.

Comment: Right I meant $H(X,Y) \leq 2n$, that was a mistake.  I will have to think about your comment. I expected $H(f(X,Y)) \leq H(X,Y)$  on the principle that entropy equals information and you can't increase the amount of information by applying a deterministic function.

Comment: I think it is not very helpful to think about entropy as information in this case. In particular, for differential entropy this notion is not always unproblematic. What you are probably thinking of is the data processing inequality (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Mutual_information).

Comment: How about if we restrict ourselves to discrete random variables?

Comment: In that case one would have to show that $H[f(X,Y)]\le H[X,Y]$ for $f(x,y)=xy$ and I am not completely sure whether that holds. However, you said that $H[Y]=n$ which is the dimension of $Y$. Is that a coincidence or on purpose? If so, $H[XY]$ must be smaller or equal than $n$ since $n$ is the entropy of the uniform distribution in $n$ dimensions which has maximal entropy (discrete case). This means you cannot increase the entropy of $Y$ no matter what you do with it.

Comment: Thanks that looks like exactly what I wanted.  However @WillNelson gave an example which seems to contradict this bound.  Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16148/discussion-between-lembik-and-fabee).

Comment: My above comment only holds for binary $Y$.

Comment: I'm joining the conversation a  bit late and cannot really spare the time to go into a detailed conversation here, but the use of $n$ as both a dimension and some type of value or bound for entropy seems very odd to me. Why conflate the two concepts? Even if $X$ is a *scalar* (one-dimensional), its entropy can be arbitrarily large. If $X$ is equiprobable over $2^n$ distinct values, its entropy is $n$.

Comment: I'd look at a very simple example. Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent (scalar, real) random variables. Let $X$ be a $2\times 2$ random matrix, which is diagonal. Its diagonal entries are $A$ and $1$. Let $Y$ be a $2\times 1$ random vector with entries $1$ and $B$. Then $XY$ is the $2\times 1$ random vector with entries $A$ and $B$. (Just multiply $X$ and $Y$.) It's easy to see that $H(X)=H(A)$ and $H(Y)=H(B)$. Also, $H(XY)=H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$. Basically, $X$ trivially encodes $A$, $Y$ encodes $B$, and $XY$ encodes both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: But what does that prove? You just found an example for which it works. It might just not work for the majority of the other examples. In particular is $X$ is not a square matrix.

Comment: @fabee For discrete distributions, we have $H(XY) \le H(X) + H(Y)$. Thus, $H(X)+H(Y)$ is an upper bound on the entropy of $XY$, as the original question seems to suggest. I constructed an example to show that this upper bound is achieved in some cases. Your answer concerns "differential entropy", an attempt to generalize Shannon's original definition of entropy from discrete to continuous distributions. I suggest also considering discrete distributions, as these are the canonical starting point in many discussions of entropy.

Comment: (cont.) In the end, I suspect the answer to this question will depend on one's definition of entropy. Unfortunately, the concept of "entropy of a distribution" does not seem to generalize very nicely from discrete to more general distributions. Lots of nice properties are lost.

Comment: Can you supply a proof for $H[XY]\le H[X]+H[Y]$? I immediately believe that the joint entropy is lower than the sum of the marginal entropies $H[X, Y]\le H[X]+H[Y]$, but for the matrix/vector product I am not so sure.

Comment: @fabee It's a simple property of Shannon entropy (for discrete distributions) that $H(f(X))\le H(X)$ for any function $f$ and any random variable $X$. The wikipedia page on Shannon entropy discusses this property. Now think of matrix multiplication as just a mapping $(X,Y)\mapsto XY$. Thus, $H(XY)\le H(X,Y)$.

Comment: I see, it is actually not that hard to show. But I think this also gives us the means to given an answer.